# plot 95% confidence interval of 20 data points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

If amount of data points is small (i.e. 20 data points). Do I need to check its normality before calculating confidence interval?

Can anyone suggests a rigorous process to plot 95% confidence interval?

Thanks!

Comment: This question confuses me. The confidence interval of _what_? If the statistic you are getting a confidence interval for takes into account sample size, then no. If it does not and is only valid under an assumption of normality, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

With so few data points and if you don't know if the distribution is normal I would look into using bootstrap confidence interval. It's a non-parametric method so you are not assuming normality. The MATLAB function `bootci` implements this method.

Here is the documentation for [`bootci`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootci.html).